# get Bluetoothdevice from the name of the device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to develop an application to send data over blue-tooth. I have been able to display the bonded devices and also the devices within  the range. Now I have a list that displays all these devices and the associated Array Adapter. When I long click on the device name , I want my application to send the required data to the long-clicked device. But How do I get the BluetoothDevice from the bluetooth name that I have stored in the arrayadapter at the corresponding position ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save BluetoothDevice as returned by Android Bluetooth discovery ACTION_FOUND receiver instead of just saving name. Later in your List Adapter, you can fetch the name from each BluetoothDevice in saved list and populate your list.

You can not retrieve BluetoothDevice from name alone. You would need address (as suggested by Hoan Nguyen).

Saving BluetoothDevice would be better and wise option.

P.S.: BluetoothDevice is parcelable, hence saving and sending it as messages won't be a problem either.

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the address of the device and then use `getRemoteDevice (String address)`

Comment: thankyou very much.... I have also saved the address for the device after your suggestion!!